# Equivalent Trigonometry, help me please

Tags: trigonometry

I have been try simplify this, could you help me?

$$\dfrac{\csc x - \cos x}{\sec x - \sin x}$$

Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried? Usually, the first step is to represent it in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Comment: Hint:  $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}$ and $\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x}.$   Use the hint and try writing out your own answer below.

Answer (score 4):

So this is what I did:

$$\frac{\csc x - \cos x}{\sec x - \sin x} = \frac{\frac{1-\sin x \cos x}{\sin x}}{\frac{1-\sin x \cos x}{ \cos x}}  = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \cot x$$

Comment: Fix the typo in the numerator.

Comment: @mattbiesecker Fixed.